# What does the lucky rock trinket do?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

The description says it feels like there is something inside, but I've got no idea how to open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't open the lucky rock trinket - you open other rocks.

It seems that with this trinket, any rock you smash will drop a coin. I had a fair number of bombs saved up when I got this trinket, so I went on a bit of a spree. Every rock smashed by my bombs dropped exactly 1 cent each. There *could* be a chance a nickel/dimes/quarters, but the RNG did not drop any over 16 bombs and multiple rocks per bomb.

Comment: This also works with the stomping attribute, where you crush Stones when walking over them. And yes, there's a chance of nickels/dimes.